# How can I make a stacked bar graph from a set of wide data using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following dataset:

```
Date Treatment Precipitation Irrigation     ET Leaching
1    5/1/2018      100%        1.4732      0.000 0.0000   1.4732
2    5/1/2018      125%        1.4732      0.000 0.0000   1.4732
3    5/1/2018       75%        1.4732      0.000 0.0000   1.4732
4    5/1/2018       50%        1.4732      0.000 0.0000   1.4732
5    5/2/2018      100%        0.0000      0.000 0.0000   0.0000
6    5/2/2018      125%        0.0000      0.000 0.0000   0.0000
7    5/2/2018       75%        0.0000      0.000 0.0000   0.0000
8    5/2/2018       50%        0.0000      0.000 0.0000   0.0000
9    5/3/2018      100%        1.5240      0.000 0.0000   1.5240
10   5/3/2018      125%        1.5240      0.000 0.0000   1.5240
11   5/3/2018       75%        1.5240      0.000 0.0000   1.5240
12   5/3/2018       50%        1.5240      0.000 0.0000   1.5240
13   5/4/2018      100%        2.3368      0.000 0.0000   2.3368
14   5/4/2018      125%        2.3368      0.000 0.0000   2.3368
15   5/4/2018       75%        2.3368      0.000 0.0000   2.3368
16   5/4/2018       50%        2.3368      0.000 0.0000   2.3368
17   5/5/2018      100%        0.0000      0.000 0.0000   0.0000
18   5/5/2018      125%        0.0000      0.000 0.0000   0.0000
19   5/5/2018       75%        0.0000      0.000 0.0000   0.0000
20   5/5/2018       50%        0.0000      0.000 0.0000   0.0000
21   5/6/2018      100%        0.7620      0.000 0.0000   0.7620
22   5/6/2018      125%        0.7620      0.000 0.0000   0.7620
23   5/6/2018       75%        0.7620      0.000 0.0000   0.7620
24   5/6/2018       50%        0.7620      0.000 0.0000   0.7620
25   5/7/2018      100%        0.0000      0.000 0.0000   0.0000
26   5/7/2018      125%        0.0000      0.000 0.0000   0.0000
27   5/7/2018       75%        0.0000      0.000 0.0000   0.0000
28   5/7/2018       50%        0.0000      0.000 0.0000   0.0000
29   5/8/2018      100%        0.0000      0.000 0.0000   0.0000
30   5/8/2018      125%        0.0000      0.000 0.0000   0.0000
31   5/8/2018       75%        0.0000      0.000 0.0000   0.0000
32   5/8/2018       50%        0.0000      0.000 0.0000   0.0000
33   5/9/2018      100%        3.3020      0.000 0.0000   3.3020
34   5/9/2018      125%        3.3020      0.000 0.0000   3.3020
35   5/9/2018       75%        3.3020      0.000 0.0000   3.3020
36   5/9/2018       50%        3.3020      0.000 0.0000   3.3020
37  5/10/2018      100%        0.0000      0.000 0.0000   0.0000
38  5/10/2018      125%        0.0000      0.000 0.0000   0.0000
39  5/10/2018       75%        0.0000      0.000 0.0000   0.0000
40  5/10/2018       50%        0.0000      0.000 0.0000   0.0000
41  5/11/2018      100%        0.9906      0.000 0.0000   0.9906
42  5/11/2018      125%        0.9906      0.000 0.0000   0.9906
43  5/11/2018       75%        0.9906      0.000 0.0000   0.9906
44  5/11/2018       50%        0.9906      0.000 0.0000   0.9906
45  5/12/2018      100%        0.0000      0.000 0.0000   0.0000
46  5/12/2018      125%        0.0000      0.000 0.0000   0.0000
47  5/12/2018       75%        0.0000      0.000 0.0000   0.0000
48  5/12/2018       50%        0.0000      0.000 0.0000   0.0000
49  5/13/2018      100%        0.0000      0.000 0.0000   0.0000
50  5/13/2018      125%        0.0000      0.000 0.0000   0.0000
51  5/13/2018       75%        0.0000      0.000 0.0000   0.0000
52  5/13/2018       50%        0.0000      0.000 0.0000   0.0000
53  5/14/2018      100%        0.3048      0.000 0.0000   0.3048
54  5/14/2018      125%        0.3048      0.000 0.0000   0.3048
55  5/14/2018       75%        0.3048      0.000 0.0000   0.3048
56  5/14/2018       50%        0.3048      0.000 0.0000   0.3048
57  5/15/2018      100%        0.0000      0.000 0.0000   0.0000
58  5/15/2018      125%        0.0000      0.000 0.0000   0.0000
59  5/15/2018       75%        0.0000      0.000 0.0000   0.0000
60  5/15/2018       50%        0.0000      0.000 0.0000   0.0000
61  5/16/2018      100%        0.0000      0.000 0.0000   0.0000
62  5/16/2018      125%        0.0000      0.000 0.0000   0.0000
63  5/16/2018       75%        0.0000      0.000 0.0000   0.0000
64  5/16/2018       50%        0.0000      0.000 0.0000   0.0000
65  5/17/2018      100%        0.0000      0.762 0.0000   0.7620
66  5/17/2018      125%        0.0000      0.762 0.0000   0.7620
67  5/17/2018       75%        0.0000      0.762 0.0000   0.7620
68  5/17/2018       50%        0.0000      0.762 0.0000   0.7620
69  5/18/2018      100%        0.0000      0.000 0.0000   0.0000
70  5/18/2018      125%        0.0000      0.000 0.0000   0.0000
71  5/18/2018       75%        0.0000      0.000 0.0000   0.0000
72  5/18/2018       50%        0.0000      0.000 0.0000   0.0000
73  5/19/2018      100%        0.0000      0.000 0.0000   0.0000
74  5/19/2018      125%        0.0000      0.000 0.0000   0.0000
75  5/19/2018       75%        0.0000      0.000 0.0000   0.0000
76  5/19/2018       50%        0.0000      0.000 0.0000   0.0000
77  5/20/2018      100%        0.0000      0.762 0.3048   0.4572
78  5/20/2018      125%        0.0000      0.762 0.3048   0.4572
79  5/20/2018       75%        0.0000      0.762 0.3048   0.4572
80  5/20/2018       50%        0.0000      0.762 0.3048   0.4572
81  5/21/2018      100%        0.0000      0.000 0.1016   0.0000
82  5/21/2018      125%        0.0000      0.000 0.1016   0.0000
83  5/21/2018       75%        0.0000      0.000 0.1016   0.0000
84  5/21/2018       50%        0.0000      0.000 0.1016   0.0000
85  5/22/2018      100%        0.0000      0.000 0.2794   0.0000
86  5/22/2018      125%        0.0000      0.000 0.2794   0.0000
87  5/22/2018       75%        0.0000      0.000 0.2794   0.0000
88  5/22/2018       50%        0.0000      0.000 0.2794   0.0000
89  5/23/2018      100%        0.0000      0.000 0.3810   0.0000
90  5/23/2018      125%        0.0000      0.000 0.3810   0.0000
91  5/23/2018       75%        0.0000      0.000 0.3810   0.0000
92  5/23/2018       50%        0.0000      0.000 0.3810   0.0000
93  5/24/2018      100%        0.0000      0.000 0.3080   0.0000
94  5/24/2018      125%        0.0000      0.000 0.3080   0.0000
95  5/24/2018       75%        0.0000      0.000 0.3080   0.0000
96  5/24/2018       50%        0.0000      0.000 0.3080   0.0000
97  5/25/2018      100%        0.0000      1.016 0.3572   0.0000
98  5/25/2018      125%        0.0000      1.016 0.3572   0.0000
99  5/25/2018       75%        0.0000      1.016 0.3572   0.0000
100 5/25/2018       50%        0.0000      1.016 0.3572   0.0000
101 5/26/2018      100%        0.0000      0.000 0.4588   0.0000
102 5/26/2018      125%        0.0000      0.000 0.4588   0.0000
103 5/26/2018       75%        0.0000      0.000 0.4588   0.0000
104 5/26/2018       50%        0.0000      0.000 0.4588   0.0000
105 5/27/2018      100%        0.0000      1.016 0.5842   0.0000
106 5/27/2018      125%        0.0000      1.016 0.5842   0.0000
107 5/27/2018       75%        0.0000      1.016 0.5842   0.0000
108 5/27/2018       50%        0.0000      1.016 0.5842   0.0000
109 5/28/2018      100%        0.0000      0.000 0.4064   0.0000
110 5/28/2018      125%        0.0000      0.000 0.4064   0.0000
111 5/28/2018       75%        0.0000      0.000 0.4064   0.0000
112 5/28/2018       50%        0.0000      0.000 0.4064   0.0000
113 5/29/2018      100%        0.0000      0.635 0.5334   0.0000
114 5/29/2018      125%        0.0000      0.635 0.5334   0.0000
115 5/29/2018       75%        0.0000      0.635 0.5334   0.0000
116 5/29/2018       50%        0.0000      0.635 0.5334   0.0000
117 5/30/2018      100%        0.0000      0.000 0.1270   0.0000
118 5/30/2018      125%        0.0000      0.000 0.1270   0.0000
119 5/30/2018       75%        0.0000      0.000 0.1270   0.0000
120 5/30/2018       50%        0.0000      0.000 0.1270   0.0000
121 5/31/2018      100%        0.0000      0.000 0.4064   0.0000
122 5/31/2018      125%        0.0000      0.000 0.4064   0.0000
123 5/31/2018       75%        0.0000      0.000 0.4064   0.0000
124 5/31/2018       50%        0.0000      0.000 0.4064   0.0000
125  6/1/2018      100%        0.0000      0.000 0.3810   0.0000
126  6/1/2018      125%        0.0000      0.000 0.3810   0.0000
127  6/1/2018       75%        0.0000      0.000 0.3810   0.0000
128  6/1/2018       50%        0.0000      0.000 0.3810   0.0000
129  6/2/2018      100%        0.7366      0.000 0.1270   0.0000
130  6/2/2018      125%        0.7366      0.000 0.1270   0.0000
131  6/2/2018       75%        0.7366      0.000 0.1270   0.0000
132  6/2/2018       50%        0.7366      0.000 0.1270   0.0000
133  6/3/2018      100%        0.0762      0.000 0.2032   0.0000
134  6/3/2018      125%        0.0762      0.000 0.2032   0.0000
135  6/3/2018       75%        0.0762      0.000 0.2032   0.0000
136  6/3/2018       50%        0.0762      0.000 0.2032   0.0000
137  6/4/2018      100%        0.0000      0.000 0.4572   0.0000
138  6/4/2018      125%        0.0000      0.000 0.4572   0.0000
139  6/4/2018       75%        0.0000      0.000 0.4572   0.0000
140  6/4/2018       50%        0.0000      0.000 0.4572   0.0000
141  6/5/2018      100%        0.7112      0.000 0.4572   0.0000
142  6/5/2018      125%        0.7112      0.000 0.4572   0.0000
143  6/5/2018       75%        0.7112      0.000 0.4572   0.0000
144  6/5/2018       50%        0.7112      0.000 0.4572   0.0000
145  6/6/2018      100%        0.0000      0.762 0.2794   0.0000
146  6/6/2018      125%        0.0000      0.762 0.2794   0.0000
147  6/6/2018       75%        0.0000      0.762 0.2794   0.0000
148  6/6/2018       50%        0.0000      0.762 0.2794   0.0000
149  6/7/2018      100%        0.2032      0.000 0.5080   0.0000
150  6/7/2018      125%        0.2032      0.000 0.5080   0.0000
151  6/7/2018       75%        0.2032      0.000 0.5080   0.0000
152  6/7/2018       50%        0.2032      0.000 0.5080   0.0000
153  6/8/2018      100%        0.1270      1.016 0.2286   0.0000
154  6/8/2018      125%        0.1270      1.016 0.2286   0.0000
155  6/8/2018       75%        0.1270      1.016 0.2286   0.0000
156  6/8/2018       50%        0.1270      1.016 0.2286   0.0000
157  6/9/2018      100%        0.0000      0.000 0.4064   0.0000
158  6/9/2018      125%        0.0000      0.000 0.4064   0.0000
159  6/9/2018       75%        0.0000      0.000 0.4064   0.0000
160  6/9/2018       50%        0.0000      0.000 0.4064   0.0000
161 6/10/2018      100%        0.0000      0.000 0.2286   0.0000
162 6/10/2018      125%        0.0000      0.000 0.2286   0.0000
163 6/10/2018       75%        0.0000      0.000 0.2286   0.0000
164 6/10/2018       50%        0.0000      0.000 0.2286   0.0000
165 6/11/2018      100%        0.0000      1.016 0.4572   0.0000
166 6/11/2018      125%        0.0000      1.016 0.4572   0.0000
```

I would like to use gpplot2 to make a stacked bar graph. Ideally, it seems like I could make it with the following code:

```
ggplot(data, aes(fill="response source"", y=response, x=date)) + 
 geom_bar(position="fill", stat="identity")
```

however, my current format doesn't work this way. I would need a singular response value column and a 'response source' column stating if the value is from Precipitation, Irrigation, ET, or Leaching.

Is there another way to code my ggplot to work with my data in the current format? I do not think that there is an efficient way to convert my current data format to the ideal format.

Thanks in advance for any help and please let me know if I have made a mistake in my post and need to change anything, as I am fairly inexperienced with Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can reshape into 'long' format with `pivot_longer`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)

df1 %>%
   mutate(Date = mdy(Date)) %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = Precipitation:Leaching,
          names_to = "response_source", values_to = "response") %>%
   ggplot(aes(fill= response_source, y=response, x=Date)) + 
     geom_bar(position="fill", stat="identity")
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Date = c("5/1/2018", "5/1/2018", "5/1/2018", "5/1/2018", 
"5/2/2018", "5/2/2018", "5/2/2018", "5/2/2018", "5/3/2018", "5/3/2018", 
"5/3/2018", "5/3/2018", "5/4/2018", "5/4/2018", "5/4/2018", "5/4/2018", 
"5/5/2018", "5/5/2018", "5/5/2018", "5/5/2018", "5/6/2018", "5/6/2018", 
"5/6/2018", "5/6/2018", "5/7/2018", "5/7/2018", "5/7/2018", "5/7/2018", 
"5/8/2018", "5/8/2018", "5/8/2018", "5/8/2018", "5/9/2018", "5/9/2018", 
"5/9/2018", "5/9/2018", "5/10/2018", "5/10/2018", "5/10/2018", 
"5/10/2018", "5/11/2018", "5/11/2018", "5/11/2018", "5/11/2018", 
"5/12/2018", "5/12/2018", "5/12/2018", "5/12/2018", "5/13/2018", 
"5/13/2018", "5/13/2018", "5/13/2018", "5/14/2018", "5/14/2018", 
"5/14/2018", "5/14/2018", "5/15/2018", "5/15/2018", "5/15/2018", 
"5/15/2018", "5/16/2018", "5/16/2018", "5/16/2018", "5/16/2018", 
"5/17/2018", "5/17/2018", "5/17/2018", "5/17/2018", "5/18/2018", 
"5/18/2018", "5/18/2018", "5/18/2018", "5/19/2018", "5/19/2018", 
"5/19/2018", "5/19/2018", "5/20/2018", "5/20/2018", "5/20/2018", 
"5/20/2018", "5/21/2018", "5/21/2018", "5/21/2018", "5/21/2018", 
"5/22/2018", "5/22/2018", "5/22/2018", "5/22/2018", "5/23/2018", 
"5/23/2018", "5/23/2018", "5/23/2018", "5/24/2018", "5/24/2018", 
"5/24/2018", "5/24/2018", "5/25/2018", "5/25/2018", "5/25/2018", 
"5/25/2018", "5/26/2018", "5/26/2018", "5/26/2018", "5/26/2018", 
"5/27/2018", "5/27/2018", "5/27/2018", "5/27/2018", "5/28/2018", 
"5/28/2018", "5/28/2018", "5/28/2018", "5/29/2018", "5/29/2018", 
"5/29/2018", "5/29/2018", "5/30/2018", "5/30/2018", "5/30/2018", 
"5/30/2018", "5/31/2018", "5/31/2018", "5/31/2018", "5/31/2018", 
"6/1/2018", "6/1/2018", "6/1/2018", "6/1/2018", "6/2/2018", "6/2/2018", 
"6/2/2018", "6/2/2018", "6/3/2018", "6/3/2018", "6/3/2018", "6/3/2018", 
"6/4/2018", "6/4/2018", "6/4/2018", "6/4/2018", "6/5/2018", "6/5/2018", 
"6/5/2018", "6/5/2018", "6/6/2018", "6/6/2018", "6/6/2018", "6/6/2018", 
"6/7/2018", "6/7/2018", "6/7/2018", "6/7/2018", "6/8/2018", "6/8/2018", 
"6/8/2018", "6/8/2018", "6/9/2018", "6/9/2018", "6/9/2018", "6/9/2018", 
"6/10/2018", "6/10/2018", "6/10/2018", "6/10/2018", "6/11/2018"
), Treatment = c("100%", "125%", "75%", "50%", "100%", "125%", 
"75%", "50%", "100%", "125%", "75%", "50%", "100%", "125%", "75%", 
"50%", "100%", "125%", "75%", "50%", "100%", "125%", "75%", "50%", 
"100%", "125%", "75%", "50%", "100%", "125%", "75%", "50%", "100%", 
"125%", "75%", "50%", "100%", "125%", "75%", "50%", "100%", "125%", 
"75%", "50%", "100%", "125%", "75%", "50%", "100%", "125%", "75%", 
"50%", "100%", "125%", "75%", "50%", "100%", "125%", "75%", "50%", 
"100%", "125%", "75%", "50%", "100%", "125%", "75%", "50%", "100%", 
"125%", "75%", "50%", "100%", "125%", "75%", "50%", "100%", "125%", 
"75%", "50%", "100%", "125%", "75%", "50%", "100%", "125%", "75%", 
"50%", "100%", "125%", "75%", "50%", "100%", "125%", "75%", "50%", 
"100%", "125%", "75%", "50%", "100%", "125%", "75%", "50%", "100%", 
"125%", "75%", "50%", "100%", "125%", "75%", "50%", "100%", "125%", 
"75%", "50%", "100%", "125%", "75%", "50%", "100%", "125%", "75%", 
"50%", "100%", "125%", "75%", "50%", "100%", "125%", "75%", "50%", 
"100%", "125%", "75%", "50%", "100%", "125%", "75%", "50%", "100%", 
"125%", "75%", "50%", "100%", "125%", "75%", "50%", "100%", "125%", 
"75%", "50%", "100%", "125%", "75%", "50%", "100%", "125%", "75%", 
"50%", "100%", "125%", "75%", "50%", "100%"), Precipitation = c(1.4732, 
1.4732, 1.4732, 1.4732, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.524, 1.524, 1.524, 1.524, 
2.3368, 2.3368, 2.3368, 2.3368, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.762, 0.762, 0.762, 
0.762, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.302, 3.302, 3.302, 3.302, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0.9906, 0.9906, 0.9906, 0.9906, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0.3048, 0.3048, 0.3048, 0.3048, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0.7366, 0.7366, 0.7366, 0.7366, 0.0762, 0.0762, 0.0762, 0.0762, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.7112, 0.7112, 0.7112, 0.7112, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2032, 
0.2032, 0.2032, 0.2032, 0.127, 0.127, 0.127, 0.127, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Irrigation = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.762, 0.762, 0.762, 0.762, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.762, 0.762, 0.762, 0.762, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.016, 1.016, 1.016, 1.016, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1.016, 1.016, 1.016, 1.016, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.635, 0.635, 
0.635, 0.635, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.762, 0.762, 0.762, 0.762, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1.016, 1.016, 1.016, 1.016, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1.016), ET = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.3048, 
0.3048, 0.3048, 0.3048, 0.1016, 0.1016, 0.1016, 0.1016, 0.2794, 
0.2794, 0.2794, 0.2794, 0.381, 0.381, 0.381, 0.381, 0.308, 0.308, 
0.308, 0.308, 0.3572, 0.3572, 0.3572, 0.3572, 0.4588, 0.4588, 
0.4588, 0.4588, 0.5842, 0.5842, 0.5842, 0.5842, 0.4064, 0.4064, 
0.4064, 0.4064, 0.5334, 0.5334, 0.5334, 0.5334, 0.127, 0.127, 
0.127, 0.127, 0.4064, 0.4064, 0.4064, 0.4064, 0.381, 0.381, 0.381, 
0.381, 0.127, 0.127, 0.127, 0.127, 0.2032, 0.2032, 0.2032, 0.2032, 
0.4572, 0.4572, 0.4572, 0.4572, 0.4572, 0.4572, 0.4572, 0.4572, 
0.2794, 0.2794, 0.2794, 0.2794, 0.508, 0.508, 0.508, 0.508, 0.2286, 
0.2286, 0.2286, 0.2286, 0.4064, 0.4064, 0.4064, 0.4064, 0.2286, 
0.2286, 0.2286, 0.2286, 0.4572), Leaching = c(1.4732, 1.4732, 
1.4732, 1.4732, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.524, 1.524, 1.524, 1.524, 2.3368, 
2.3368, 2.3368, 2.3368, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.762, 0.762, 0.762, 0.762, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.302, 3.302, 3.302, 3.302, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0.9906, 0.9906, 0.9906, 0.9906, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.3048, 
0.3048, 0.3048, 0.3048, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.762, 0.762, 
0.762, 0.762, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.4572, 0.4572, 0.4572, 
0.4572, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
"16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", 
"27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", 
"38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", 
"49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", 
"60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", 
"71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", 
"82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", "91", "92", 
"93", "94", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99", "100", "101", "102", 
"103", "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", "109", "110", "111", 
"112", "113", "114", "115", "116", "117", "118", "119", "120", 
"121", "122", "123", "124", "125", "126", "127", "128", "129", 
"130", "131", "132", "133", "134", "135", "136", "137", "138", 
"139", "140", "141", "142", "143", "144", "145", "146", "147", 
"148", "149", "150", "151", "152", "153", "154", "155", "156", 
"157", "158", "159", "160", "161", "162", "163", "164", "165"
))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know that this was possible. I run your code as you've written it, but get a response saying that I cannot find the function "pivot_longer", despite having tidyr loaded. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: @Trev have you loaded `library(tidyr)` if so, can you check `packageVersion('tidyr')` and if you have an older version of `tidyr`, may be reinstall thew new version of tidyr

Comment: Thanks again @akrun. That solved the issue, although the code is still not working for me. When I try to only change the dataset without doing the ggplot, I get the error "Error: Unknown column `response_source` 
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace". Do you know why this might happen?

Comment: @Trev I created the column in `pivot_longer` i.e. `df1 %>%
   mutate(Date = mdy(Date)) %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = Precipitation:Leaching,
          names_to = "response_source", values_to = "response")` can you check the column names after this step

Comment: My mistake, it seems like I just incorrectly updated the package. Everything is working now, thanks again for taking the time to help me out!